# Python doesn't generate new code

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models

I have a code generator like this:

## extra_funcs.py

```
def id_generator(size=4, chars=string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits):
    return ''.join(random.choice(chars) for _ in range(size))
```

And have a Django model like this:

## models.py

```
from .extra_funcs import id_generator

def generator(digit):
    ret = id_generator(digit)
    return ret

class Service(models.Model):
    business = models.ForeignKey(Business)
    sub_service = models.ForeignKey('self', blank=True, null=True, related_name='sub_services')
    code = models.CharField(max_length=20, default=generator(6), blank=False, editable=False)
    en_title = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=False)
    update = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

I don't know why it doesn't generate new values it just return once-value each time ! What should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass a callable as default, not call the callable:

```
from .extra_funcs import id_generator

def generator:
    ret = id_generator(6)
    return ret

class Service(models.Model):
    business = models.ForeignKey(Business)
    sub_service = models.ForeignKey('self', blank=True, null=True, related_name='sub_services')
    code = models.CharField(max_length=20, default=generator, blank=False, editable=False)
    en_title = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=False)
    update = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

Django check if `default` is callable.

`generator(6)` is not callable because return value and this value is assign to default.

Try `lambda`:

```
default=lambda: generator(6)
```

You don't need to define `generator` function

```
default=lambda: id_generator(6)
```

Unfortunatelly this is not recommended, because lambda cannot be serialized by migrations. See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#default (thanks @knbk)

Comment: Note that a lambda cannot be serialized. This won't work in combination with migrations, which serializes the field with all its arguments.

Answer (score 1):

You can't have `default=function(value)`, you can only have `default=function` as the statement is executed immediately at the first read-parsing cycle.

So you can't pass a callable. Here is how you can rewrite your code:

```
from .extra_funcs import id_generator

def generator():
    digit = 6
    ret = id_generator(digit)
    return ret

class Service(models.Model):
    business = models.ForeignKey(Business)
    sub_service = models.ForeignKey('self', blank=True, null=True, related_name='sub_services')
    code = models.CharField(max_length=20, default=generator, blank=False, editable=False)
    en_title = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=False)
    update = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```